# Can I reference a variable, rather than an instance of a variable?

Tags: c#

I have the following two classes:

```
class MoveTo : Routine
{
    Creature creature;
    Entity target;

    public MoveTo(Creature Creature, Entity Target)
    {
        this.creature = Creature;
        this.target = Target;
    }

    public Act()
    {
        creature.MoveTowards(Target);
    }
}
```

... and...

```
class Creature
{
    Entity ClosestTarget { get; set; } 
    Routine currentBehavior;
    //...
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
creature.ClosestTarget = OldClosestTarget;
Routine moveToClosestTarget = new MoveTo(creature, creature.ClosestTarget); //pass "ClosestTarget" as the "Target" parameter

//...

moveToClosestTarget.Act(); //Move towards OldClosestTarget
creature.ClosestTarget = NewClosestTarget;
moveToClosestTarget.Act(); //What I want: Move towards NewClosestTarget. What it actually does: Move towards OldClosestTarget
```

The reference object in the MoveTo routine will stay with OldClosestTarget, as well it should.

But for this particular use case, I need it to do the opposite: I want to pass in reference specifically to the Creature.ClosestTarget variable, rather than a reference to the instance it currently contains.

Can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Another layer of indirection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's deceptive how little code needs to change:

```
class MoveTo : Routine
{
    Creature creature;
    Func<Entity> target;

    public MoveTo(Creature Creature, Func<Entity> Target)
    {
        this.creature = Creature;
        this.target = Target;
    }

    public Act()
    {
        creature.MoveTowards(Target());
    }
}
```

later

```
new MoveTo(creature, () => creature.ClosestTarget)
```

This is classical lazy evaluation in the lambda calculus.

The other way would be define `class Indirect<T> { public T Value; }` and change `ClosestTarget` from `Entity` to `Indirect<Entity>`, give `MoveTo` a reference to the same `Indirect<Entity>`  Then when the `Value` of the `Indirect` changes, both classes see the new value.

Comment: +1. Be careful on what you capture in lambda... It may be better to have `Func<Creature, Entity>` and pass current creature to it if computing target  related to current creature is common enough. Otherwise if `creature` variable is changed (i.e. in a loop) you'll get very strange behavior...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Sure, but I figured the original code made it a separate constructor parameter for a reason... that the target isn't always coupled to the creature passed in.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: One could also solve that by binding the delegate directly to an instance method instead of building a lambda, e.g. `new MoveTo(creature, creature.GetClosestTarget)`  Unfortunately there's no nice syntax for referencing the getter method of a property.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Three different ways to solve my problem if we include the delegate approach in the comments: I can't believe none of them occured to me.
         
I think I'll go for the Indirect<T> approach: I find myself preferring the syntax that way, it's more self-explanatory. 
         
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public MoveTo(Creature Creature)
    {
        this.creature = Creature;
    }

    public Act()
    {
        creature.MoveTowards(this.creature.ClosestTarget);
    }
```

Given your code you can initialize using just the `Creature` object, and use its `ClosestTarget`. Although if you're using the `MoveTowards` method in `Creature`, why even bother passing the `Target`? You can use the `ClosestTarget` of that `Creature` object itself

Comment: This still reads `ClosestTarget` only once, in the constructor.  And it makes the `MoveTo` class less generic, since it must always use `Creature.ClosestTarget`.

Comment: Now it should at least work, agree with the dependency on the property.

Comment: As Ben said, including the Target as a parameter is to maximise generic... uh... ness? Genericality? Regardless, I want to be able to feed more than just the nearest tree into MoveTo().
         
As for not simply skipping all the shenanigans and just using the creature's MoveTowards() routine: I'm building a behavior tree. MoveTowards() is a single-frame method that moves the creature in the direction of the target, while MoveTo() is a multiframe routine that keeps on moving the creature towards the target before Succeeding or Failing depending on whether they make it or are interrupted.