# Lazy Evaluation in a Setter

Tags: c#, lambda

I have [recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373468/can-i-reference-a-variable-rather-than-an-instance-of-a-variable/26373540#26373540) how to use lambda's for lazy evaluation, which allows me to do this:

```
MoveTo moveToTargetCreature = 
    new MoveTo(() => parent.Context.TargetCreature);
```

...

```
public class MoveTo
{
    Func<Creature> Target { get; set; }

    public MoveTo(Func<Creature> Target)
    {
        this.Target = Target;
    }

    public Act(Creature parent)
    {
        parent.MoveTowards(Target().Position);
    }
}
```

... and call the routines Act() method later to make the creature move to whatever the closest target is.

This works fine when all I'm trying to do is retrieve a variable (simply invoke Target()), but what if I want to set it? For example:

```
SetVariable setTargetCreatureToClosestCreature = 
    new SetVariable(parent.Context.TargetCreature, () => parent.Context.ClosestCreature);
```

...

```
public class SetVariable
{
    Creature VariableToSet { get; set; }
    Func<Creature> Target { get; set; }

    public SetVariable(Creature VariableToSet, Func<Creature> Target)
    {
        this.VariableToSet = VariableToSet;
        this.Target = Target;
    }

    public Act(Creature parent)
    {
        VariableToSet = Target(); 
        //What I want: Set "parent.Context.TargetCreature" to Target()

        //What it does: Sets the internal "VariableToSet" to Target(), but 
        //leaves "parent.Context.TargetCreature" as what it was when initialised.
    }
}
```

And if I alternatively use Func and the lambda syntax, it won't compile because you can't assign to a method call.

What would be the appropriate syntax for this?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do here. Can you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: My apologies. The code shown is actually the problem I'm trying to solve, but I've added a clarification to the comment in the last code block that should help.

Comment: No, I disagree. The code shown isn't the problem you're trying to solve. It's your proposed solution that you think will solve your real problem. What is your real problem?

Comment: Alright, well... the full problem is a matter of code reuse in a data-driven Behavior Tree that uses classes to represent routines. I'm using the tree to iterate through a List of other Creatures and store the closest one that matches a set of criteria, like "IsAlive" and "IsGeneticallyCompatible". The result of this routine then needs to be stored in the creatures Context object, to be retrieved by future routines that need that information.

Comment: Without being able to create a SetVariable class like the one above, I have to either store the results of this routine in a single, contextual variable ("ClosestCreatureMatch") or create a load of unique routines to store them in unique variables ("SetClosestCorpse", "SetClosestMate", "SetClosestPrey").

Comment: So, in effect, you're trying to track a "currently active creature"? And you're using lambdas because either (1) you want to be able to change the source of the currently active creature or (2) you want to give different object trees different currently active creatures?

Comment: For this particular use case, that's a fair summary. 
 
This is extremely unlikely to be the only use case, though. I've had similar reuse problems with things like enumerator indices (GetNextTree_Index, GetNextCreature_Index, etc) and collections of objects (NearbyTrees, NearbyEdibleTrees, EdibleTreesInSight, etc), where I have to create unique Routine classes just to populate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you'd want?

```
public class SetVariable
{
    Creature ObjectToSet { get; set; }
    Action<Creature, Creature> SetterAction { get; set; }

    public SetVariable(Creature objectToSet, Action<Creature, Creature> setterAction)
    {
        this.ObjectToSet = objectToSet;
        this.SetterAction = setterAction;
    }

    public Act(Creature parent)
    {
        this.SetterAction(parent, this.ObjectToSet);
        //the setter action would be defined as (when instantiating this object):
        //SetVariable mySet = new SetVariable(null, (target, val) => target.PropertyName = val);
        //it will set the PropertyName property of the target object to val (in this case val=null).
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, reading up on Action<T> now it looks like what I need. I'll have to do some experimentation to be sure, but I think I can get something fairly elegant with this.

Comment: Ok, but please consider that I don't think it's good from an architecture point of view to use delegates (in the sense of action /function pointers) in this way. Essentially, if you want to set property X of object y to value val, I advise you to do just that: `y.X = val;`. Code which delegates much is very unreadable, and there are better ways to accomplish this functionality. If you post a question with your broader functional requirements, I'll be happy to take a look.